# How is this binary subtraction done?

Tags: binary

[image: Binary subtraction photo]

How is the binary subtraction done in the photo attached? I know there are several ways to compute it, but I'm specifically asking for the way my professor did it in that photo.

Comment: @an4s Glad to see that three of the serial down votes were removed. Sometimes this happens but it will be all right :)

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Yes, I realized it was one user who was not happy with my review to their answer. They downvoted 5 of my answers, of which 3 were reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask your professor for what the specific notation means, but it appears that s/he is just starting from the right hand side, and they are putting a line through the digit on the top line whenever they need to take a term  from the next column.

So the zero in the third column becomes a "10" in binary as a 1 is taken from the fourth column.  Since the number in the fourth column is a 0, a 1 can't be taken from it, so it becomes a "10" by taking a 1 from the fifth column (so that 1 becomes a 0).  Now the the "10" in the fourth column becomes a 1 (since we need to take a one for the third column). That leaves a 1, which is written on the top row of the fourth column.  I hope you get the idea as one continues in this way.  This sounds like the Tom Lehrer song about new math.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the right:

- zero from one is one
- one from one is zero
- one from zero is not possible

  - try to borrow from next column but cannot
  - borrow from next to next column
  - leaving one in next column and zero in next to next column
  - one from two is one
- zero from one is one
- one from what is now zero is not possible

  - borrow from next column
  - leaving zero in next column
  - one from two is one
- zero from what is now zero is zero
- zero from zero is zero
- zero from zero is zero